# Linq saving twice?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider my AddToCart action method. My question concerns what happens from my comment //3. save or update shoppingCartItem:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddToCart(
            [Bind("ShoppingCartItemProductId,ShoppingCartItemQuantity")]
            ViewModelAddToCart model)
    {
        // Initialize session to enable SessionId
        // TODO: Check if cookie exists
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("_Name", "MyStore");

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string SessionId = HttpContext.Session.Id;

        var ShoppingCart = new ShoppingCart()
        {
            SessionId = SessionId,
            CreateDate = dt,
            Title = "My shopping cart (" + dt.ToShortDateString() + ")"
            // (not in use yet) CustomerId = 0
        };

        var ShoppingCartItem = new ShoppingCartItem()
        {
            ProductId = model.ShoppingCartItemProductId,
            Quantity = model.ShoppingCartItemQuantity
        };

        // 1. If a ShoppingCart exist with current SessionId, get ShoppingCartId from
        // that one and use it in the ShoppingCartItem
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Query for ShoppingCart containing current SessionId.
            var cartInfo =
                (from Cart in _context.ShoppingCarts
                 where Cart.SessionId == SessionId
                 select new { TempId = Cart.Id })
                    .SingleOrDefault();
            if (cartInfo != null)
            {
                // *** [ Use existing ShoppingCart ] ***
                // 2. Set ShoppingCartId for ShoppingCartItem
                ShoppingCartItem.ShoppingCartId = cartInfo.TempId;
            }
            else
            {
                // *** [ Create a new shoppingCart ] ***
                _context.ShoppingCarts.Add(ShoppingCart);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                // 2. Set ShoppingCartId in ShoppingCartItem
                ShoppingCartItem.ShoppingCartId = ShoppingCart.Id;
            }

            // 3. save or update shoppingCartItem
            // Query for ShoppingCartItem containing current ProductId
            var cartItemInfo =
                (from CartItem in _context.ShoppingCartItems
                 where CartItem.ProductId == model.ShoppingCartItemProductId
                 select new { TempQty = CartItem.Quantity })
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            if (cartItemInfo != null)
            {
                // 4. update quantity for existing ShoppingCartItem
                ShoppingCartItem.Quantity += cartItemInfo.TempQty; // current quantity + added quantity
                _context.ShoppingCartItems.Update(ShoppingCartItem);
            }
            else
            {
                // 4. create a new shoppingCartItem
                _context.ShoppingCartItems.Add(ShoppingCartItem);
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View("Index", "Home");
    }
```

ShoppingCarts are saved correctly. If one exists containing the current SessionId, it will add a ShoppingCartItem with the existing ShoppingCartId.

ShoppingCartItems, on the other hand, are not quite done right. They are saved, but when a product is added more than once, a new ShoppingCartItem is created with the new quantity. The first table record with the current product is checked, and that quantity is 1. Then 1 is added, making the quantity 2 for the new ShoppingCartItem.

To illustrate, this is a data-view of the table ShoppingCartItems:

```
//Product gets added first time:
[Id]   [ProductId] [Quantity] [ShoppingCartId]
[6092] [5]         [1]        [6091]

//The same product is added again:
[Id]   [ProductId] [Quantity] [ShoppingCartId]
[6092] [5]         [1]        [6091]
[6093] [5]         [2]        [6091]
```

Of course, the desired behaviour would be like this:

```
//Product gets added first time:
[Id]   [ProductId] [Quantity] [ShoppingCartId]
[6092] [5]         [1]        [6091]

//The same product is added again:
[Id]   [ProductId] [Quantity] [ShoppingCartId]
[6092] [5]         [2]        [6091]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It only seems to be saving at one location, at await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); right before it redirects to action (after // 5. update quantity for existing ShoppingCartItem). I think I'm just not addressing the correct record of the table. How can I get the right row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you are creating a new shopping cart item, that will be a different item than the previous shopping cart item. 
If you don't define the shoppingcartitemID it will be a new item, the update has no way to know that it has to update an item instead of creating a new one.

Solutions, get the ShoppingCartItemID from the shopping cart item that you found with the old quantity, and set it in the new shopping cart item, so EF can know it has to update an existing item.

The other solution is to delete the old entry before creating this one, it's not recommended since it's 2 operations and complexity is greater.